# How to filter field value and send data into the firestore collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular9

In the firestore collection named 'doctor' there are different fields including the field 'role'. I want to add the doctors into firestore with a role named doctor. How can I do this? Following is the code that successfully adds data into the database. If you can, tell me the way to add data with a specific field name. Thanks in advance.

service.ts

```
create_Newdoctor(Record){
  return this.firestore.collection('doctors').add(Record);
}
```

component.ts

```
CreateRecord(docForm: NgForm){
  let Record = {};
  Record['fullName']=this.fullName;
  Record['email']=this.email;

  this.DoctorService.create_Newdoctor(Record).then(res=> {
    this.fullName="";
    this.email="";
    console.log(res);
        this.message = "Added";
  }).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that `Record` is a javascript object, and how you create a document in Cloud firestore, is by passing an object with all the filled attributes into the `add` method like what you did in `service.ts`, and  how you pass in an attribute is via `Record[ATTRIBUTE_NAME] = ATTRIBUTE_VALUE`

Hence I believe what  you  need to  just to add in the line  `Record[‘role’] = “doctors”` into `component.ts`